# Eigenvalue of Orthogonal Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving the question

> If $\lambda$ is (complex) eigenvalue of an orthogonal transformation $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ then $|\lambda|=1$.

Here, "$\lambda$ is complex eigenvalue" means it is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $T$. (For example, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is real orthogonal, and $i$ is a complex eigenvalue of it, although it has no real eigenvalues).

I am facing the following problem.

1) $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ can be uniquely extended to a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\hat{T}\colon \mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$.

2) Since $TT^t=I$ is orthogonal, $\hat{T}$ satisfies $\hat{T}\hat{T}^*=I$ (where $\hat{T}^*=$ conjugate transpose of $\hat{T}$).

3) Characteristic poltnomial of $T$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is same as characteristic polynomial of $\hat{T}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

4) Any root $\lambda$ of characteristic polynomial of $\hat{T}$ satisfies $|\lambda|=1$.

I didn't understand (1) (2) and (3). Can you help me?

Answer (score 5):

Let $v$ be an (complex) eigenvector with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. The calculation

$v^*v = v^*T^*Tv=(Tv)^*(Tv) = \lambda^*\lambda v^*v$

immediately shows $\lambda^*\lambda=1$, hence the assertion.

Considering the other question: You should interpret 1)-3) as "Take a matrix representation of $T$ and interpret it as an matrix over $\mathbb C$.".

Comment: So here you are looking at extension of $T$ to a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$. I want to also see "basis-free" arguments for (1), (2) and (3).

Comment: "basis-free" in linear-algebra often goes along with using the tensor-product. Tensoring with $\mathbb C$ gives us the map $\hat{T}: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$.

Comment: I am teaching this course for undergraduates, and I have not introduced "Tensors". Is there easy way to discuss (1) (2) and (3)?

Comment: @Groups if you're teaching undergrads, why the preoccupation with basis-independent? It's hard to do without the tensor algebra

Comment: Are you OK with $\{1,i\}$ as a basis for the complex numbers over the reals? Then every complex vector $u$ can be written as $v+wi$ with $v,w$ real vectors, and $T(u)$ defined as $T(v)+iT(w)$.

Comment: That might work well for 1) and 2). But how will u see easily that the determinant of a linear map behaves well with that construction?
That is obvious if you work with matrix representations and its somehow obvious working with tensor products (it is just the fact that exterior powers commute with base change).

But how will you get information about the determinant of $v+wi \mapsto Tv+iTw$ without using one of the above methods, i.e. choosing a base or working with tensor operations? Undergraduates usually don't even know how to introduce determinant without the choice of a base, do they?